# r remove sparse terms by type of documents

Tags: r, tm

I'm new with corpus, I have a big corpus where there are 4 types of documents. I want remove sparse terms inside the types. I can't just create separated corpus because they had a lot of transformations before, using some post I created a TermDocumentMatrix with the name of the type in each column, but I can't find the way to remove sparse terms by type. 
Any idea? Thanks you!!

Just for example i removed sparse terms for all the corpus

```
TDM_1 <- removeSparseTerms(TDM, 0.98) 
inspect(TDM_1) <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 27, documents: 2583)>> 
Non-    /sparse entries: 3591/66150 Sparsity : 95% Maximal term length: 12  Weighting : term frequency (tf) 

TDM_1$dimnames (Types of documents to remove sparse terms)
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the coments, I realized that my corpus was wrong. I changed the transformer functions and created one TermDocumentMatrix by type. But now I have another problem to remove sparse terms. Suppose my TDM are tdm_1, tdm_2.

```
library(tm)
library(Rstem)

data(crude)

spl <- runif(length(crude)) < 0.7
crude_1 <- crude[spl]
crude_2 <- crude[!spl]

controls <- list(
  tolower = TRUE,
  removePunctuation = TRUE,
  stopwords = stopwords("english"),
  stemming = function(word) wordStem(word, language = "english")
)

tdm_1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude_1, controls)
tdm_2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude_2, controls)

## Don´t work.

for(i in 1:2){
  assign(paste0("TDM_", i), 
     removeSparseTerms(paste0('tdm_', i), 0.98)
}

## But this is ok.

removeSparseTerms(tdm_1, 0.98)
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I'll try inspect(TDM_1)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 27, documents: 2583)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3591/66150
Sparsity           : 95%
Maximal term length: 12
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

TDM_1$dimnames (Types of documents to remove sparse terms

Comment: post it in your question..

Comment: can you supply is with a reproducable example and how you want the outcome to look like? As it is now, it is guessing what you want.

Comment: Sorry I don´t now how. I have a corpus with 4 types of documents, lets say type1 with 100 documents, type2 with 50 documents and so on. The types are differents things, so I can't remove sparse terms without distinction. I'm looking a way to "split" the corpus to remove sparse terms by type, dimnames of the corpus

Comment: One suggestion would be to use the `crude` dataset from tm package to generate a [mcve] for others to help