# r remove sparse terms from more than one tdm

Tags: r, tm

This comes from [r remove sparse terms by type of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870373/r-remove-sparse-terms-by-type-of-documents?noredirect=1#comment53579757_32870373). Now I have two TermDocumentMatrix to remove sparse terms, I have tried this but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
library(tm)
library(Rstem)

data(crude)

spl <- runif(length(crude)) < 0.7
crude_1 <- crude[spl]
crude_2 <- crude[!spl]

controls <- list(
  tolower = TRUE,
  removePunctuation = TRUE,
  stopwords = stopwords("english"),
  stemming = function(word) wordStem(word, language = "english")
)

tdm_1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude_1, controls)
tdm_2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude_2, controls)

## Don´t work.

for(i in 1:2){
  assign(paste0("TDM_", i), 
  removeSparseTerms(paste0('tdm_', i), 0.98)
}

## But this is ok.

removeSparseTerms(tdm_1, 0.98)
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Your parens aren't balanced in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  assign(paste0("TDM_", i), 
         removeSparseTerms(get(paste0('tdm_', i)), 0.98))
}
TDM_1
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 707, documents: 16)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 1245/10067
# Sparsity           : 89%
# Maximal term length: 13
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
TDM_2
# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 308, documents: 4)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 377/855
# Sparsity           : 69%
# Maximal term length: 16
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```